# Dual map is zero if and only if map is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, duality-theorems

A problem from Linear Algebra Done Right (Third Ed): **Suppose $W$ is finite dimensional** and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. Prove that $T=0$ if and only if its dual $T' \in \mathcal{L}(W', V')=0$.

I am confused by the information that $W$ is finite dimensional. Why is that required, while nothing is said about finite dimensionality of $V$ ?

There is a solution here: [Does that fact that the dual map is zero imply that the map is zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226719/does-that-fact-that-the-dual-map-is-zero-imply-that-the-map-is-zero)  but I am more interested in the reason for the assumptions.

I was able to solve it (or so I thought) without using a contrapositive argument or the assumption on $W$ which is what worries me.

EDIT: Here is my argument. Since T' = 0,
 we get $\phi_w(Tv) = 0 \forall  \phi_w$, which yields Tv = 0 for all v, hence T = 0. I can "reverse" the argument to get the converse. What is my error?

Comment: Maybe you should add your argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the statement is correct also for infinite-dimensional $W$, as the key point is the

> **Proposition**. If $W$ is a vector space, $w \in W$ such that $f(w)=0$ for all $f \in W'$, then $w = 0$.

(This follows from the fact that if $w \ne 0$, we can extend $\{w\}$ to a basis $B$ of $W$ and define $f$ on the basis $B$ by $f(w) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in B \setminus \{w\}$, and extend by linearity. Then $f \in W'$ and $f(w) \ne 0$).

But this argument relies on the axiom of choice (this is always needed if we want to construct bases on infinite-dimensional vector spaces), and may be wrong if the axiom of choice is not to be used. As far as I know, in the mentioned book, the basis extension theorem is not proved for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, and hence cannot be used.

As we do not need a basis of $V$ in our argument, not dimensionality assumption if needed for $V$.

Comment: See [here on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/79437) for an example of a infinite-dimensional vector space $V$ such that $V' = 0$.

Comment: The explanation above by martini is correct. In my book Linear Algebra Done Right, the focus is on finite-dimensional vector spaces. Thus the book does not prove that every infinite-dimensional vector space has a basis (the proof requires the use of the axiom of choice or an equivalent result). Hence this exercise has the hypothesis that W is finite-dimensional. The solution to the exercise does not need to use a basis of V, and thus I did not include a finite-dimensionality hypothesis for V in the exercise.

Comment: This chain of equivalences seems to work for the infinite-dimensional cases without invoking the axiom of choice: \begin{equation}
T=0\iff\mathrm{range}\,T=\{0\}\iff(\mathrm{range}\,T)^0=W'=\mathrm{null}\,T'\iff T'=0.
\end{equation}
Can you see any flaw in it? Thanks.

Comment: The chain of equivalences above does use the axiom of choice in the case when $W$ is infinite-dimensional. Without the axiom of choice, $W'$ might equal $\{0\}$, and thus the backward direction of your second if and only if might not hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that $W'=\{0\}$ breaks the second iff. But I didn't get why **with** the Axiom of Choice, $W'$ might not equal $\{0\}$?