# Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $W$ finite-dimensional. Then $T=0\iff T'=0$. Do we really need $W$ to be finite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, exercise 3.F.15 says: Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Prove that $T=0$ if and only if $T'=0$.

I can see two solutions. The **first** one is this chain of equivalences
\begin{equation}
T=0\iff\mathrm{range}\,T=\{0\}\iff(\mathrm{range}\,T)^0=W'=\mathrm{null}\,T'\iff T'=0.
\end{equation}

The **second** one is more traditional: Suppose $T=0$. Then
\begin{equation}
    T'(\psi)=\psi\circ T = \psi\circ 0 = 0
\end{equation}
for any $\psi\in W'$. Then, $T'=0$.

Now suppose $T'=0$. Then, for any $\psi\in W'$,
\begin{equation}
    T'(\psi)=0=\psi\circ T
\end{equation}
Because $\psi\circ T$ must be zero for any $\psi$, we can conclude $T=0$.

**Both solutions do not require $W$ to be finite-dimensional, so why do the exercise include this requirement?**

I can see a possible flaw in the **second** solution: if the composition of two functions is zero, this does not mean that at least one of then is zero. What may happen is some combination of $T$ and $W$ where the composition is zero for all $\psi\in W'$ but $T\neq 0$. However, I cannot find an counterexample, possibly in the infinite-dimensional case, where this is the case.

However, I cannot see any possible flaw in the **first** solution.

Comment: Certainly the first solution does not require $W$ to be finite dimensional. Looking at the book it seems like the proof of $range(T)^{0} = null T'$ unnecessarily assumes $V,W$ are finite dimensional, probably for its' second part.

Comment: Yes. There is actually a comment that the first part doesn't assume $V$ and $W$ to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: I found an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654256/dual-map-is-zero-if-and-only-if-map-is-zero

Answer (score 0):

Your second proof is essentially correct. You can be a little more complete about it as follows.

$\psi \circ T = 0$ implies $(\psi \circ T)(v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. So we have that  $\psi(T(v)) = 0$ for all $v \in V$ and $\psi \in W'$. For a fixed $v$, the the fact that $\psi(T(v)) = 0$  for all $\psi \in W'$ implies that $T(v) = 0$. Since this applies for all $v\in V$ we have $T(v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. So $T = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you say anything about the need for $W$ to be finite-dimensional? Can we really get rid of it?

Comment: I was trying to say there's no need for $W$ to be finite-dimensional, since you basically proved it without assuming $W$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: The statement in the answer above that "$\psi(T(v)) = 0$ for all $\psi \in W'$ implies that $T(v) = 0$" requires the axiom of choice (or some equivalent) when $W$ is infinite-dimensional. Otherwise, we cannot eliminate the possibility that $W' = \{0\}$, which would certainly imply that $\psi(T(v)) = 0$ for all $\psi \in W'$.